# Returning List in a IEnumerable method

Tags: c#

Let's suppose I have a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetList()
{
   var list = new List<string>()
   {
      "1",
      "2"
   };

   return list;
}
```

The method returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, in the method though I return a List, because the List derives from IEnumerable *(wrong word I guess, correct me if I'm wrong)* this is possible.

But when I use the returned value in another place such as:

```
var returnList = GetList();
```

Now, *returnList* is a IEnumerable and that's totally fine.

**My questions are:**

1. Is the value converted into IEnumerable when I return it as a List in the method?
2. If there is, does this conversion slow down the general program, just like `ToList()` does?

Comment: `List<T>` **IS** `IEnumerable<T>`, so no, no conversion is happening.

Comment: *Test* to see if there is a slow down.

Comment: No conversion takes place, so the second question is moot. See duplicates for more reading material.

Comment: But with List you can do more operations, if it was IEnumerable, why didn't they just replace IEnumerable with List

Comment: @HereticMonkey proper benchmarking is an art.

Comment: It's same as to ask how much effort it would take to convert Steve into a Human

Comment: @Tim my dog is called Steve.

Comment: @CodeCaster And one should learn that art early and practice it often...

Comment: @CodeCaster: lol, i was referring to OP :D

Comment: @Steve: You should only expose to the caller what is really necessary. Then you are free to change the implementation without breaking any code.

Comment: @Steve "why didn't they just replace IEnumerable with List?" I assume you mean the return type of `GetList()`. It's a good question. And it could also have been an `IList<string>`. It depends on what the class type wants to promise to the consumers of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no conversions being done, `IList<>` already implements (or in other words, *already is*) `IEnumerable<>`. What you get out of your function is exactly the list you send and nothing stops the caller from getting back a variable of type `List<>` out of it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. `IEnumerable<T>` is an `Interface`. `List<T>` implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Anything that implements a given interface can be used as if its type is the interface.
2. There is no conversion.